# Android intent-filter pathPattern numeric matching

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm adding an intent filter to my android application and I want it to catch requests that go http://www.somedomain.com/[numericValue] .  I only want to catch it if the path is numeric, but if it has text, I don't care about it.

I tried the pathPattern of [0123456789]*, but that didn't work.  Is this possible to do?

Comment: Impractical, but you could try brute-forcing it with something like `http://www.somedomain.com/0*1*0*2*0*3*0*4*0*5*0*6*0*7*0*8*0*9*1*1*2*1*3*1*4*1*5*1*6*1*7*1*8*1*9*2*2*3*2*4*2*5*2*6*2*7*2*8*2*9*3*3*4*3*5*` and so on.

Comment: @KTibow Unfortunately this does not seem to work. I tried that, but the found that a simple case as /0*1* only matches /1 og /01. It seems to be impossible. I just found a way - see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `pathPattern` is not a full regex. Rather, it uses a "simple glob", where `*` means zero or more of the immediately preceding character -- in your case, zero or more `]` characters.

Off the top of my head, I do not see how you can convert your desired pattern into something that can readily match a "simple glob".

Answer (score 0):

I have tested KTibow sample but that does not work.

But a way to hack it is that it is possible to add multiple data elements and solve it like this, so you get all cases starting with a numeric value. It is not perfect but seems like the only option based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element#path) and that it does not seems possible to do something like /0*1* as it for some reason only matches /1 and /01 when tested.

```
 <data
    android:host="example.com"
    android:pathPattern="/0.*"
    android:scheme="https" />
<data
    android:host="example.com"
    android:pathPattern="/1.*"
    android:scheme="https" />
<data
    android:host="example.com"
    android:pathPattern="/2.*"
    android:scheme="https" />
<data
    android:host="example.com"
    android:pathPattern="/3.*"
    android:scheme="https" />
<data
    android:host="example.com"
    android:pathPattern="/4.*"
    android:scheme="https" />
<data
    android:host="example.com"
    android:pathPattern="/5.*"
    android:scheme="https" />
<data
    android:host="example.com"
    android:pathPattern="/6.*"
    android:scheme="https" />
<data
    android:host="example.com"
    android:pathPattern="/7.*"
    android:scheme="https" />
<data
    android:host="example.com"
    android:pathPattern="/8.*"
    android:scheme="https" />
<data
    android:host="example.com"
    android:pathPattern="/9.*"
    android:scheme="https" />
```